# Möbius inversion formula for two functions f(x) and g(x)

Tags: number-theory, sequences-and-series

Given the 2 functions $$ g(x)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f\left(\frac{x}n\right)\log(n)\;, $$ how can I use Möbius inversion to recover $f$ from $g$?? I believe that

$$ f(x)=  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu (n)g\left(\frac{x}n\right)\log(n)\;. $$ Here 'mu' is the Möbius function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a well known inversion formula stated in Section 27.5 of the NIST Handbook of Mathematical Functions (DLMF online):
$$G(x) = \sum_{n \leq x} F(x/n) \iff F(x) = \sum_{n \leq x} \mu(n) G(x/n).$$ So there are two options:

1. We can write your $g(x)$ with a floor function, as 
   $$g(x) = \sum_{n \leq x} f\left(\left\lfloor \frac{x}{n} \right\rfloor\right) \log n,$$ and then apply the DLMF manual's formula; or
2. Essentially do this, but bound $f(x/n) \log n$ for large $n > x$, and then apply a variant of the stated formula.

Answer (score 6):

Suppose $f(x)=x^{10}$. Then $$g(x)=\sum_1^{\infty}x^{10}n^{-10}\log n=Cx^{10}$$ where $C=\sum_1^{\infty}n^{-10}\log n$ is a very small positive constant. Then $$\sum_1^{\infty}\mu(n)g(x/n)\log n=Cx^{10}\sum_1^{\infty}\mu(n)n^{-10}\log n=CDx^{10}$$ where $D=\sum_1^{\infty}\mu(n)n^{-10}\log n$ is a very small constant. We can't have $CD=1$, so we can't have $$f(x)=\sum_1^{\infty}\mu(n)g(x/n)\log n$$

Comment: I was just perusing old posts and I'm confused here - why can't we have $CD=1$? It looks to me like $C=-\zeta'(10)$ and $D$ is the reciprocal of this (based on the Dirichlet series for $\zeta'(10)^{-1}$).

Comment: @anon, my thinking was that $C$ is surely much smaller than 1, and $|D|$ is surely even smaller, so their product must be smaller still. Is that wrong?

Comment: You're right; looks like I was confusing the order of differentiation and taking the reciprocal in my Dirichlet series thinking.

Comment: You can use a variant of Perron's formula cited [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%27s_formula#Generalizations). Namely, if $G(s) = \sum_{n \geq 1} a(n) n^{-s}$ is the Dirichlet series of $a(n)$ and $F(s) = \int_0^{\infty} f(x) x^{s-1} dx$ is the Mellin transform of $f$, then 
$$\sum_{n \geq 1} a(n) f(x/n) = \frac{1}{2\pi\imath} \int_{c-\imath\infty}^{c+\imath\infty} F(s) G(s) x^s ds,$$ where $c > \sigma_G$ is sufficiently large. Here, your function $G(s) = -\zeta^{\prime}(s)$ so that ...

Comment: ... $$g(x) = -\frac{1}{2\pi\imath} \int_{c-\imath\infty}^{c+\imath\infty} \zeta^{\prime}(s) \left(\int_0^{\infty} f(t) t^{s-1} dt\right) x^s ds.$$ Now if the integral $\int_0^{\infty} f(t) t^{s-1} dt$ is well enough behaved so that it does not have any poles, then by the residue theorem:
$$g(x) = x \log x + \int_0^{\infty} f(t) \log t dt.$$

Answer (score 0):

I was re-reading through some old posts on this site. I want to respond to Gerry's concern given in [the comment from above](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/8269/gerry-myerson) in more complete detail. For the series Gerry cites using $g(x) = x^{10}$, we have (by uniformly convergent series analysis, and differentiation of this formal series) that
$$g(x) = -\zeta^{\prime}(10) \cdot x^{10}.$$

Fair enough, here the exact $|\zeta^{\prime}(10)| \approx 0.000697033$, indeed a small constant factor. Let's take $C_0 := -\zeta^{\prime}(10)$. By similar reasoning on the second series expansion that results for $f(x)$, we see that

$$f(x) = \sum_{n \geq 1} \mu(n) g(x/n) \log n = C_0 \cdot x^{10} \times \frac{d}{ds}\left[\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}\right]\Biggr\rvert_{s=10}.$$

By formally computing the last derivative of the reciprocal of the Riemann zeta function with respect to $s$, we have that $f(x) = x^{10}$, e.g., the former notation does in fact yield $CD = 1$ in this case.

Note that we have used the property that the Dirichlet series over the Moebius function satisfies $$\sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{\mu(n)}{n^s} = \frac{1}{\zeta(s)}, \forall \Re(s) > 1.$$

Comment: You get $$C_0\cdot x^{10} \cdot \biggl(-\frac{\zeta'(10)}{\zeta(10)^2}\biggr) = \biggl(\frac{\zeta'(10)}{\zeta(10)}\biggr)^2\cdot x^{10}\,,$$ the factor is a little smaller than $5\cdot 10^{-7}$.